# Is these pens blue or green? or Are these pens blue or green?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, grammatical-number

Is these pens blue or green? or Are these pens blue or green?
Which one is true?

Comment: Only you can say whether it's true that you blue pens or green pens. Please stop using *true* improperly in English. It does not have anything to do with right and wrong, for there are many a wrong thing which is true and many a right thing which is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these pens blue or green?

is the correct sentence, since `pens` are plural.

If it was a single pen:

> Is this pen blue or green?

would be correct.